# Package rails app as gem or something else reusable?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, packaging

I'm looking for a guide on how to package a rails app as a gem or something reusable like that..

At work we build a lot of client rails apps where wordpress is too bloggy(and php) and radient and the other ruby cms's seem a little clunky to fit them perfectly..

So im building (you guessed it) yet another CMS for simple sites using the common factors ive seen across multiple sites..

What would be perfect would be, being able to say

```
$: MyCMSName new sitename
```

To setup the common defaults, and then:

```
$: rails g MyCMSName:downloads
```

Or

```
$: rails g MyCMSName:galleries
```

---

Also it would also be nice to say:

```
$: MyCMSName new sitename --with-galleries --with-downloads
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way [RefineryCMS](http://refinerycms.com/) works.

Rather than wasting your time creating yet another CMS, I suggest you [download the source](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms) and help in development.

There are a few rails engine extensions available too, including a gallery. The main developer is open to pull requests and can often be found on irc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. ive seen refinery, but im not a huge fan.. will consider forking it and tweaking it to my liking though, to be honest my needs are quite simple and at the moment theres perhaps 500 lines of code identical in all the sites so i'm just looking for a way of gemming them up, instead of manually updating all the sites whenever i fix a bug in one, it'd be like an update..

Comment: RefineryCMS is to complicated to be good example for such a simple task.

So, how did you package them ?